# search and replace using grep (not sed)

Tags: sed, grep

I’ve been reading about `sed` and found that it was evolved from `grep` command.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed ,

> First appearing in Version 7 Unix, sed is one of the early Unix
>   commands built for command line processing of data files. It evolved
>   as the natural successor to the popular grep command. The original
>   motivation was an analogue of grep (g/re/p) for substitution, hence
>   "g/re/s".

**Sed search and replace**

```
sed 's/old/new/' Example.txt
```

Thus, I was wondering if `grep` can perform the search and replace function just like `sed`.

If this is possible, please let me know how to accomplish the same via `grep`, and not via `sed`.

Comment: `grep` stands for _globally search a regular expression and print_. So it is out of its scope to do replacements. I suggest you to use the right tool for the right job. `sed` or `awk` are better suited for this.

Comment: When wikipedia says about sed `It evolved as the natural successor to the popular grep command.` it means that grep was used to search and print a pattern, while sed can search and print or even replace a pattern.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeVasiliou, my concerns has been addressed with your explanation. Now I understand why `sed` was created after that.
I would like to accept this as the best answer, however this is a "comment".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep` is only meant to (and was only initially) print(ing) the lines matching a pattern. That's what `grep` means (based on the `g/re/p` `ed` command).

Now, some `grep` implementations have added a few features that encroaches a bit on the role of other commands. For instance, some have some `-r`/`--include`/`--exclude` to perform part of `find`'s job.

GNU `grep` added a `-o` option that makes it perform parts of `sed`'s job as it makes it edit the lines being matched.

`pcregrep` extended it with `-o1`, `-o2`... to print what was matched by capture groups. So with that implementation, even though it was not designed for that, you can actually replace:

```
sed 's/old/new/'
```

with:

```
pcregrep --om-separator=new  -o1 -o2 '(.*?)old(.*)'
```

That doesn't work properly however if the capture groups match the empty string. On an input like:

```
XoldY
Xold
oldY
```

it gives:

```
XnewY
X
Y
```

You could work around that using even nastier tricks like:

```
PCREGREP_COLOR= pcregrep --color=always '.*old.*' |
  pcregrep --om-separator=new -o1 -o2 '^..(.+?)old(.+)..' |
  pcregrep -o1 '.(.*).'
```

That is, prepend and append `\e[m` (coloring escape sequence) to all matching lines to be sure there is at least one character on either side of `old`, and strip them afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

No, grep could not perform substitutions (in one call), that is why there was a clear need for sed (and later awk as a better language for text processing).

Answer (score 1):

[ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep), which is compatible with [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep), has a `--replace` option, so

```
ugrep --replace=new old Example.txt
```

is the equivalent of

```
sed s/old/new/ Example.txt
```

[ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) also has an equivalent command-line flag:

```
rg --replace new old Example.txt
```