# Grep global find replace

Tags: grep, regular-expression, string

Is there a way to grep for a regular expression on an Ubuntu server and then find and replace it with another string? I am using the following command right now, but it doesn't account for actually changing the grepped string:

```
grep --recursive --ignore-case “string”
```

If I use awk or sed how would I write it to replace for instance "wavbyte" with "gitship" for all instances where "wavbyte" occurs for my entire server?

Comment: You want sed, not grep. Also, you're using "smart" quotes, so grep will search for the literal string `“string”`, including the quotes. You want `"string"` (or probably even better, `'string'`, unless you plan on using parameter expansion in the search term).

Comment: `grep` isn't used to replace strings. It's used for finding strings. To replace them, you need `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: So would it be something like

Comment: sed --recursive --ignore-case "string", "replacement-string"

Comment: Related: [search and replace using grep (not sed)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373420/search-and-replace-using-grep-not-sed) - however you *could* use `grep --recursive --files-with-matches` to construct a list of file names to be passed to `sed`

Comment: Is there not a way to do it in one command where it searches for all instances and then replaces them?

Comment: @CodyRutscher you can do your own command by putting all that in a function or script: `sed-ri(){ e="$1"; shift; find "$@" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "$e"; }` then `sed-ri 's/foo/bar/g' files and dirs ...`

Comment: @Goro your edits are changing the meaning of the question again.

Comment: @roaima Thank you so much! Actually, I was on a very long chat last night with the OP (link below) and his problem was completely not relevant at all to his question. Given that I solved his problem, I rewarded the question to reflect the problem. If this is not acceptable we can rollback. Apologies!

Comment: @Goro I've already rolled back. Part of the problem, I think, is that you don't use the summary field to explain why you have made an edit. In this case if you had added a summary such as, "After long chat OP actually wants a different question; editing to new requirement" or something then it would have been more obvious that you were intentionally changing the meaning.

Comment: @roaima . Thank you for the note! You are completely correct! Indeed, I neglected adding summary about the objective of the changes.... I will definitely take this into account in the future! Your feedback is appreciated thanks ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this command

```
grep -rl "wavbyte" somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's/wavbyte/gitship/g'
```

You can try `find` and `sed`

```
find /some_path -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Do I replace "matchstring" with the new or old string and what if I want to do it from the root directory of the server?

Comment: For instance if I am replacing "wavbyte" with "gitship" from the root directory of the Ubuntu server would it be:

Comment: find / -type f -exec sed -i 's/wavbyte/gitship/g' {} \;

Comment: Right, but wavbyte is in a lot of different places in the server. How am I going to memorize all of those locations and then go in by hand and change to gitship?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83881/discussion-between-cody-rutscher-and-goro).

Comment: Hi. How can do i escape slashes if i have them on string?

Comment: You don't need to escape slashes if you switch to a different separator. This is useful when replacing URLs and paths for example: `sed -i.bak -- 's#oldpath#newpath#gI' myfile`